# iOS UIText Field Place holder font size/style

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, font-size

Anybody know of a way you can set the font size for a Placeholder in a UITextField?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by programmatically setting up the value for the key @"_placeholderLabel.font"

`[self.input setValue:[UIFont fontWithName: @"American Typewriter Bold" size: 20] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.font"];`

Comment: it is distorting vertical alignment of my placeholder.

Answer (score 4):

I found out the font size and style for the placeholder font can be adjusted by setting the font style for the actual text in interface builder.

Comment: Is it possible to change the placeholder text using code? If possible can u please post the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can override drawPlaceholderInRect to do this....

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
         [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
}
```

Comment: where is the method call? when will this method be called?

Comment: @PradeepReddyKypa you can override this method in UITextField, I believe it is called as ios is about to render the placeholder.

Comment: If you use this method, watch out for the text placement in iOS 7. It no longer takes the vertical alignment of the textField into account. You must move the origin of the rectangle yourself.

Comment: @Justin: Yes it is DEPRECATED from iOS 7.0 and above, We have to use `drawInRect:withAttributes:` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is another form of setting font\font colour property.

```
if ([self.textField respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedPlaceholder:)]) {
    self.textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                       initWithString:placeholder
                                       attributes:@{
                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: newColor,
                                                    NSFontAttributeName:font,
                                                    NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:offset]
                                                    }];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Cannot set placeholder text's color, because deployment target is earlier than iOS 6.0");
        // TODO: Add fall-back code to set placeholder color.
}
```

Pay attention to `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName`, and it resolve the wrong vertical alignment problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue as Ankit , i solved it by changing font sizes in TextField delegates.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"American Typewriter Bold" size: 12]];
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if (range.location == 0 && range.length == 0) {
        [textField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"American Typewriter Bold" size: 18]];
    }
    if(range.location == 0 && range.length == 1){
        [textField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"American Typewriter Bold" size: 12]];
    }
    return YES;
}
```