# Changing placeholder Font of a textfiled in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

How to change the Font of the Placeholder of the text filed?
Is this possible to change the default font of the Placeholder of the text filed?
If anyone know it please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767753/ios-uitext-field-place-holder-font-size-style

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a subclass of `UITextField` and overwrite the `drawPlaceholderInRect:`

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]];
}
```

Comment: (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:19.0]];
}  put this code,but it shows a waning that myviewcontroller may not respond t placeholder.And also nothing changes in font

Comment: @stackiphone You need to create a subclass of `UITextField` and overwrite the method.

Answer (score 2):

`@fannheyward`'s answer was good. However, `– drawInRect:withFont:` is deprecated in iOS 7.0. In iOS 7, you should use:

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiTC-Light" size:14.0];    
    [self.placeholder drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}]
}
```

please also note that the "real" font name may be different from the one it shows on interface builder. You can use the following code to get the "real" name of available fonts in your project:

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
    }
}
```